# Return current location from multiple min values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables, with the level of education, personal details, current location, and income. Education is linked to personal details, which is separately linked to current location (don't ask why, old DB). Income is also linked to personal details.

I'm trying to identify where the person with the lowest level of education, but with the highest level of income, is currently residing. The issue arises that I have about 30 people with the (same) lowest level of education, and the same income bracket.

Current code is as follows:

```
select  p.name,
        min(e.level),
        max(i.income),
        l.city
from    education as e
join    person_det as p
on      e.person_ID = p.ID
join    location as l
on      p.CityID = l.CityID
join    income as i
on      p.job_ID = i.job_id
Order by e.level ASC, i.income DESC;
```

However, this only seems to return 1 person, not all the people I need.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work with the multiple criteria?

Comment: Your query doesn't have `GROUP BY`. I suggest you try adding `GROUP BY p.name, l.city` before `ORDER BY` and remove the semi-colon `;` in `on p.job_ID = i.job_id;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting only one answer because of the `min(e.level0)`.  You could try just sorting the list by `e.level ASC, i.income DESC`, and looking at the first few items.

Otherwise, I think you need to use a nested query. The inner query would determine the `min(e.level)`, and the outer query would find records matching `min_e`, ordered by i.income DESC.  It is hard to print other info, besides the max i.income.

Try something like this:

```
select p.name, e.level, i.income, l.city
from person as p
join education as e on e.person_ID=p.ID
join income as i on p.job_ID=i.job_id
join location as l on p.CityID=l.CityID
where e.level = (select min(level) from education)
order by i.income DESC;
```

Comment: Any suggestion on how to write the nested query?